# example of QOS_DIFFSERV usage

Tags: c++, msdn, qos

I receive an error when I use this `QOS_DIFFSERV`. I read about the way it is used in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374056(v=vs.85).aspx). I am wondered if I have written this code correctly?

```
auto diffClass = (QOS_DIFFSERV*)pointer;
diffClass->ObjectHdr.ObjectType = QOS_OBJECT_DIFFSERV;      
diffClass->DSFieldCount = 1;
auto rule = (QOS_DIFFSERV_RULE*)diffClass->DiffservRule;
rule->ConformingOutboundDSField = 48;
rule->ConformingUserPriority = 7;
rule->InboundDSField = 48;
rule->NonConformingOutboundDSField = 48;
rule->NonConformingUserPriority = 7;
diffClass->ObjectHdr.ObjectLength = sizeof(QOS_DIFFSERV) + sizeof(QOS_DIFFSERV_RULE);
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Mind to present a [MCVE] here as required?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the error is 'ERROR_INVALID_DIFFSERV_FLOW'